# write byte array to csv file with java

Tags: java, csv, byte

I have to upload a file attachment and send it via an *HTTP GET* request to a server location. I am using IBM websphere integration designer to implement this functionality.

I have the attachment as a byte array and it has to be converted to an Excel *.csv* file.

Please help me understand how to write a .csv file using a byte array.

Comment: may be this will help ? - http://bgsuryaprakash.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/convert-csv-file-data-into-byte-array/

Comment: There's not enough info here. What have you tried? What exactly does the byte array contain (as in what does the info mean)? How do you want it stored in the .csv file?

Comment: HTTP GET cannot be used to upload much data (limited size). HTTP POST could do (multiform part), or HTTP PUT (uploading a file). In general one would encode the bytes with Base64 as pure ASCII and then could pass it.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a byte array. Let's say.

```
 byte[] byteArray = ThisIsWhereMyByteArrayIsComingFrom.getArray();
 String convertedString = new String(byteArray);
```

That gets the string value of whatever your byte array is. Then you can either, use a csv library to output whatever it is to a file.